# Sending two keys in series during autocompletion confirmation

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, autocompletion, plugin-coc

I have the following mapping:

```
inoremap <expr><CR> pumvisible() && complete_info().selected != -1? "\<C-y>" : "\<CR>"
inoremap <expr><Space> pumvisible() && complete_info().selected != -1? "\<C-y>" : "\<Space>"
```

The idea here is that if I have a completion menu open & and item selected, then pressing `Enter` or `Space` will select that item from the completion menu. Notice that `<C-y>` is the built-in combination to confirm a selection. This works fine.

Now, I want to expand the functionality of this so that whenever I press `Space`, it will select an item from the list **and** type a literal whitespace. I tried the following:

```
inoremap <expr><Space> pumvisible() && complete_info().selected != -1? "\<C-y>\<Space>" : "\<Space>"
```

This does not work (it behaves as if only space was pressed), & I suspect it's because the keys are sent simultaneously. I tried using a regular space character instead of the symbol and it behaved the same way. What can I do?

EDIT: Just to make my question clearer, here is what happens when I select an autocompletion option using the `Enter` key:

[image]

No problems here, all works as intended. What I want to do now is that if I had pressed `Space` instead of `Enter`, then it would do the exact same thing as it did before, but also add a whitespace at the end. With the current settings I am using, this is what happens instead:

[image]

Comment: "select and type literal" is the default behavior of vim.  What do you dislike about the default way?

Comment: It's not that I have anything against the default behaviour, it's just that I don't know how to implement what I want. Obviously, what I did does not work, so I am looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use a timer to prevent keys from being pressed simultaneously. For example,

```
inoremap <C-a> <C-y><Esc>:call timer_start(100, {-> feedkeys("a ")})<CR>
```

will send `<C-y><Esc>` followed by `a<Space>` after 100ms.

Instead of 100ms, one can specify any delay, even 0ms.

Adding the above to the expr mapping for Space, we get

```
inoremap <expr><Space> pumvisible() && complete_info().selected != -1? '<C-y><Esc>:call timer_start(0, {-> feedkeys("a ")})<CR>' : '<Space>'
```

On my machine, this spits out the selected option, and after a tiny delay, adds a space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that in a mapping command, you do not need to escape `<keys>`.  This is because they are already interpreted by the `inoremap`.

```
inoremap <expr><Space> pumvisible() && complete_info().selected != -1? '<C-y><Space>' : '<Space>'
```

Comment: You're right, they don't need escaping. However, using your example doesn't change the behaviour.